# Unix how to sort whole row based on a particular match

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, awk

I have a file like this

```
$> cat testfile.txt
abc_xyz_2a      foo
dft_pqr_abc_5c  bar
pqr_ijk_1a      alpha
efg_5b          beta
ijk_pqr_5a      gamma
pqr_ijk_1b      alpha
```

I want to sort the rows based on last value of first column, after last underscore `_`, like `1a`,`2a`,`5a`,`5b`,`5c`

So this is my expected output.

```
pqr_ijk_1a      alpha
pqr_ijk_1b      alpha
abc_xyz_2a      foo
ijk_pqr_5a      gamma
efg_5b          beta
dft_pqr_abc_5c  bar
```

Could someone please suggest a way to achieve the expected output?

> What I tried

I have tried extracting the part after last underscore of first column and sort, but that would only print those keywords, not the whole line.

```
$> awk '{print $1}' testfile.txt|rev|awk -F_ '{print $1}'|rev|sort
1a
2a
5a
5b
5c
```

I guess there could be a way to hold/note the line numbers somehow and output based on that? I tried some hit and trial using `NR` in awk unsuccessfully.

Edit: Added a row in file ending with `1b` to handle another case. Changed expected output based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `gnu-awk` then you can use `PROCINFO` way of sorting an array:

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"} {
   n=split($1, a, "_")
   data[a[n]]=$0
}
END {
   for (i in data)
      print data[i]
}' file

pqr_ijk_1a      alpha
abc_xyz_2a      foo
ijk_pqr_5a      gamma
efg_5b          beta
dft_pqr_abc_5c  bar
```

Otherwise you can use `awk-sort-cut` pipeline:

```
awk '{n=split($1, a, "_"); print $0 "\0" a[n]}' file | sort -t '\0' -k2 | cut -d $'\0' -f1

pqr_ijk_1a      alpha
abc_xyz_2a      foo
ijk_pqr_5a      gamma
efg_5b          beta
dft_pqr_abc_5c  bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove out the required columns, sort it and then remove it again.

```
$ cat data
abc_xyz_2a      foo
dft_pqr_abc_5c  bar
pqr_ijk_1a      alpha
efg_5b          beta
ijk_pqr_5a      gamma


$ awk '{print substr($1, length($1)-1, 1), substr($1, length($1)), $1, $2}' data | sort -n -k1,2 | awk '{print $3,$4}'
pqr_ijk_1a alpha
abc_xyz_2a foo
ijk_pqr_5a gamma
efg_5b beta
dft_pqr_abc_5c bar
```

Here is what happens at each step of the pipeline:

```
$ awk '{print substr($1, length($1)-1, 1), substr($1, length($1)), $1, $2}' data
2 a abc_xyz_2a foo
5 c dft_pqr_abc_5c bar
1 a pqr_ijk_1a alpha
5 b efg_5b beta
5 a ijk_pqr_5a gamma

$ awk '{print substr($1, length($1)-1, 1), substr($1, length($1)), $1, $2}' data | sort -n -k1,2
1 a pqr_ijk_1a alpha
2 a abc_xyz_2a foo
5 a ijk_pqr_5a gamma
5 b efg_5b beta
5 c dft_pqr_abc_5c bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command which is much simpler and straight forward.

```
 rev   test.txt | sort  -k2 | rev


pqr_ijk_1a      alpha
abc_xyz_2a      foo
ijk_pqr_5a      gamma
efg_5b          beta
dft_pqr_abc_5c  bar
```

Comment: That doesn't work since `rev` would make `a1` out of `1a` and consequently `a5` out of `5a`.

Comment: @Ajinkya - Thanks for the answer. But when I tried adding a `1b` to the file, it isn't working as expected. But cudos for a different approach. Cheers.

Comment: @Utsav but as per you requirement the output i am getting as per your expectation. After sorting are you replacing any words.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately the example I selected worked with your answer, but it is not what I wanted exactly. Sorry for that. Thanks for the answer anyways.